# разыменование указателя на дочерний объект

Tags: c++

Структура Effect унаследавана от структуры EffectsStruct::bleeding

```
struct EffectsStruct{
            struct bleeding {
                int duration=0;
                int dmg=0;
            }bleedingObj;

            struct poisoning {
                int duration=0;
                int dmg=0;
            }poisoningObj;

            struct stunning {
                int duration=0;
                int dmg=0;
            }stunningObj;
};


struct Effect :public EffectsStruct::bleeding, public EffectsStruct::poisoning, public EffectsStruct::stunning {
   std::string type;
};
```

Я преобразую bleeding* в Effect*, но когда я пытаюсь разыменовать полученный Effect* программа вылетатет без ошибок

```
Skills::SkillStruct::Effect bleedingSet(Skills::SkillStruct::EffectsStruct::bleeding  in){
    auto b=static_cast<Skills::SkillStruct::Effect*>(&in);
    auto c=*b;
```

Comment: И как должен выглядеть, например, `type` в разыменованном `Effect`'е? Если в исходном `bleeding` его и в помине нет? И вообще — имеется небольшая память в 2 инта, вы указатель на нее преобразуете в указатель на минимум 6 интов + строку. При разыменовании вы получаете выход за границы объекта — этого уже достаточно...

Comment: Есть ощущение. что это проблема XY. Расскажите, чего Вы хотите добиться этим кодом. Возможно, тогда кто-то сможет подсказать Вам решение

Comment: В приведенном примере нет ни одного экземпляра класса `Effect`, чтобы указатель `b` мог на него указывать.

Comment: так как вы передаёте аргумент по значению `(Skills::SkillStruct::EffectsStruct::bleeding  in)`, преобразование типа не сможет объект привести к другому типу которого вообще нет. происходит исключение при работе с выдуманным объектом типа `Skills::SkillStruct::Effect`.

Comment: &user7860670 далее создается умный указатель на Effect, in нужен для того, чтобы задать в него значение

Comment: &AlexGlebe можно по подробнее(я новичок в программировании), просто на дебаге указатель на объект создается, и в нем лежат данные, я чуть более разобрался и понял, что стока в принципе не создается, наверное по этому (объект нельзя разыменовать? ), но если привести b обратно к bleeding то данные в нем лежат

Comment: &Юрий Козлов Неуверен что это поможет, но если вдруг есть идеи как это сделать лучше:В другой библиотеке есть класс Entity, который храни в себе данные о сущности. Там будут методы, которые получаю объект вложенной структуры в EffectsStruct, и соответственно используя его накладывают кровотечение и т.д, сами объекты будут хранить нужную информацию об эффекте. В объекте Entity есть вектор объектов способностей, в объекте способности есть вектор эффектов "std::vector<Effect> effects", в который по моей задумке задаются эффекты(объекты из EffectsStruct)

Comment: &Юрий Козлов Как это должно работать: сущность->метод_для_обработки_эффектов//который принимает Effect, а после преобразует его в объект вложенной структуры в EffectsStruct(сущность->вектор_способностей[номер способности]->вектор_эффектов[]->Effect)

Comment: преобразование указателя на объект сына должно работать, если вы сначала создали сына, потом передали указатель на папу, потом опять указатель на сына. **Но** так как вы послали в функцию **копию** базового класса без сына, то из копии предка вы сына не получите. Нужно было передавать указателем или ссылкой.

Comment: Чтобы написать кому-то конкретному следует использовать `@`, а не `&`. А что там происходит далее - совершенно не важно.

Comment: Для справки ТС: перед никами надо ставить ```@``` а не ```&```.

Comment: А Вам обязательно нужна эта хитрая структура с вложенными структурами? Я бы построил иначе (не хочу сказать, что оптимально, но, мне кажется, проще.) Сделал базовую структуру ```Effect```, в ней определил виртуальную функцию наложения эффекта. ```bleeding``` и прочих сделал ее потомками, переопределив в них эту функцию для получения нужного действия. В ```Entity``` передавал указатель на ```Effect``` и вызывал там эту самую функцию наложения эффекта.

Answer (score 0):

У вас тут очень накручено, но по сути, у вас есть
class A: B, C {}
т.е объект, в котором есть и поля B и поля C.  Дальше вы берете указатель,на B и делает на него указатель на A, которым он не является. Дальше естественно ничего не работает.
И непонятно почему вы используете static_cast для кастинга классов? Используйте dynamic_cast<A*>(ptr) и он честно вернет null, когда не сможет сделать cast.

Answer (score 0):

так как вы передаёте аргумент по значению `(Skills::SkillStruct::EffectsStruct::bleeding  in)`, преобразование типа не сможет объект привести к другому типу которого вообще нет. происходит исключение при работе с выдуманным объектом типа `Skills::SkillStruct::Effect`

преобразование указателя на объект сына должно работать, если вы сначала создали сына, потом передали указатель на папу, потом опять указатель на сына. Но так как вы послали в функцию копию базового класса без сына, то из копии предка вы сына не получите.

```
class B{};

class S:public B{};

void fun(B b) {
  // b - это копия объекта базового класса
  // сына там нет
  S * p = static_cast<S*>(&b);
  // указатель p указывает на несуществующий объект
  }

 int main() {
   S s;
   fun(s); }
```

чтобы всё работало, нужно передавать аргумент не копией, а ссылкой.

```
void fun(B & b) {
  // b - это ссылка на объекта базового класса
  // указатель на сына можно получить
  S * p = static_cast<S*>(&b);
  // указатель p указывает на реальный объект
  // только если вы передавали объект типа S
  }
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь